# Batch Script does not work - variables empty

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch script:

```
SET test = %TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%
SET testa = %date:.=_%
SET testb = %testa%%test%
Echo Datum:%testb%
```

This scripts generates following output:
SET test = 10_29_51

SET testa = 08_02_2013

SET testb =

Echo Datum:

Why is variable testb suddenly empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is because of the spaces between your variable and the values.

```
SET test=%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%
SET testa=%date:.=_%
SET testb=%testa%%test%
Echo Datum:%testb%
```

This should work by now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with lowercase letters?